# How can I make my python scrollbar scroll-able and canvas auto resize using grid instead of pack

Tags: python, tkinter, grid, scrollbar

I am trying to make the widgets in my canvas scroll-able and the canvas/widgets auto resize.

In my code I have "canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=new_frame, anchor='nw')" commented out. Running it this way will auto resize the widgets but the scrollbar doesn't work.

If you uncomment that line of code then scrollbar works but then the widgets don't auto resize.

I can't find a solution where .grid() is being used. A solution would be appreciated.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


def on_mousewheel(event):
    canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1 * (event.delta / 120)), "units")

def on_configure(event):
    # update scrollregion after starting 'mainloop'
    # when all widgets are in canvas
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all'))

# Create new window
new_win = tk.Tk()
new_win.focus_force()

# Create a canvas with a scrollbar
canvas = tk.Canvas(new_win)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.N + tk.S + tk.E + tk.W)

scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(new_win, command=canvas.yview)
scrollbar.grid(sticky=(N, S), row=0, column=1)
canvas.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

# --- put frame in canvas ---
new_frame = tk.Frame(canvas)
new_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.N + tk.S + tk.E + tk.W)

# canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=new_frame, anchor='nw')

# update scrollregion after starting 'mainloop'
# when all widgets are in canvas
canvas.bind('<Configure>', on_configure)
new_win.bind('<MouseWheel>', on_mousewheel)

# Add Widgets
label = tk.Label(new_frame, text="test")
label2 = tk.Label(new_frame, text="test")
label.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.N + tk.S + tk.E + tk.W)
label2.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.N + tk.S + tk.E + tk.W)


txt_box = tk.Text(new_frame)
txt_box2 = tk.Text(new_frame)
txt_box.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=tk.N + tk.S + tk.E + tk.W)
txt_box2.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=tk.N + tk.S + tk.E + tk.W)

# configure
new_win.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
new_win.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

new_frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
new_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

canvas.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
canvas.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

new_win.mainloop()
```

Comment: I recommend trying to reduce the size of the code. For example, you could use a loop to replace 19 calls to `grid_rowconfigure` with two lines of code. Likewise for creating the widgets and calling `grid`. You could easily trim your example by 75 lines or more.

Comment: Hi Brain, thank for the input. That will lessen the amount the code and make it look cleaner. However, it doesn't change the functionality.

Comment: You are probably correct, it won't likely help the functionality but it will help us understand your question better. When I look at a question and I see several hundred lines, my initial thought is that I have to look at every single line to see if there's a problem. When there are hundreds of lines it also signals that the author hasn't taken the time to try to narrow the problem down. Your goal in writing a question should always be to make it as easy as possible for people to understand and reproduce the problem.

Comment: Okay, I removed a lot of code and left the same functionality with just a few widgets.

Comment: You've now made it so that the scrollbars will never work, because there are too few widgets to require scrolling.

Comment: What do you mean by "autoresize"? Resize how? Expand in height to fill the window? Expand in width? If you expect the scrollbar to work you must use `create_window`, so it's pointless to provide an example that doesn't do that if you want the scrollbar to work.

Comment: Yeah Bryan, what I am saying is that I want to the text widgets to expand to fit the screen with create_window. I only added the function commented out to show what I am trying to accomplish. If you run the code with create_window commented out you'll notice the text widgets will resize to fit the window when expanded, I need that to work but with create_window not commented out.

Comment: Just to be clear: do you want both the text widget and the label to grow? Right now you've configured it only so that the second column will grow.

Comment: Just the text widgets to grow. I would like the labels to stay put

Answer (score 0):

First off, the only way to scroll something on the canvas is to put an object on the canvas with one of the `create_*` functions. If you add a frame to a canvas with `grid`, it cannot be scrolled. Therefore, you need to remove the line that calls `grid` on `new_frame`, and uncomment the line that calls `create_window`.

When you embed a frame into a canvas with `create_window`, you are responsible for maintaining the size of the widget. In your case you need to reset the size of the inner frame whenever the canvas itself changes size.

Since you already have a binding to `<Configure>` on the canvas, all you need to do is adjust the size of the inner frame based on the `width` parameter passed in on the event object. To do this you need to either save the id of the created window, or give the created window a tag.

Let's start by giving the window a tag, which you can do when you create the window:

```
canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=new_frame, anchor='nw', tags=('internal_frame',))
```

Next, reset the width of that frame to match the width of your canvas:

```
def on_configure(event):
    canvas.itemconfigure('internal_frame', width=event.width-10)
    ...
```

---

Note: to help visualize what is happening while debugging, it helps to give distinctive background colors to the canvas, inner frame, and window. It also helps to add padding or borders so you can see where one widget ends and another begins.